# Datalist in vb. Trying to get the specific values of a rows or cells in datalist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a datalist in vb web form.

How can i get the value in a specific rows and cells of a datalist?

I could do it for detailsview but how to do it for datalist??

Below is my code for detailsview:

```
 Dim selectedCommentAns As String = DetailsView.Rows(0).Cells(1).Text
```

I tried the same way for datalist but it dont have rows and cells to be selected.

This is the asp markup of my datalist:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListPhotoGallery" runat="server" CellPadding="5" 
    CellSpacing="12" DataKeyField="PhotographerPhotoId" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePhotoGallery" RepeatColumns="3">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" BorderColor="#C7B273" 
            BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="12px" Height="200px" 
            ImageUrl='<%# Eval("PhotographerPhotoImgPath", "images/UserUploadedPhoto/{0}") %>' 
            Width="220px" />
        <br />
        Photo No:&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="PhotographerPhotoIdLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("PhotographerPhotoId") %>' />
        <br />
        Photo Description:
        <asp:Label ID="PhotographerPhotoDescLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("PhotographerPhotoDesc") %>' />
        <br />
        Photo Name:
        <asp:Label ID="PhotographerPhotoImgNameLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("PhotographerPhotoImgName") %>' />
        <br />
        Photographer Name:
        <asp:Label ID="PhotographerIdLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("PhotographerName") %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="AddCommentBtn" runat="server" 
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PhotographerPhotoId") %>' Font-Bold="True" 
            Font-Size="Medium" onclick="AddCommentBtn_Click" Text="Add Comment" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" 
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PhotographerPhotoId") %>' Font-Bold="True" 
            Font-Size="Medium" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Order Photo" />
        <br />
```

Comment: From where do you need to get the Text? You should show as the aspx markup of your DataList.

Comment: I have edited the question with my aspx markup of datalist.. How should i do to get the text of "PhotographerPhotoIdLabel" ?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `Rows` and `Cells`, `DataList` has a property named `Items` that lets you access its collection of data-bound items:

```
Dim itemIndex As Integer = 9
Dim label As Label = DataListPhotoGallery.Items(itemIndex).FindControl("PhotographerPhotoIdLabel")
Dim text As String = label.Text
```

If you know the row and column indexes but not the item index, then you can calculate the item index like this:

- **If `RepeatDirection` is `Horizontal`:** `itemIndex = rowIndex * RepeatColumns + columnIndex`
- **If `RepeatDirection` is `Vertical`:** Post a comment if you need this because it's rather complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can access items using

```
DataListPhotoGallery.Items
```

If you want to access specific item, the you need to find object you are looking for. In this case you want to get a value of PhotographerPhotoIdLabel label.

```
var PhotographerPhotoIdLabel = DataListPhotoGallery.Items[itemsId].FindControl("PhotographerPhotoIdLabel") as Label;
var yourString = PhotographerPhotoIdLabel.Text;
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concern datasource to get the value. Please refer the below code to get the required value.

```
Dim dv As DataView
dv = CType(SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
selectedCommentAns = dv.Table.Rows[0][1]
```

Hope this will help.